# Every $2$-dimensional commutative $k$-algebra with only one prime ideal is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^2)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ an algebraically closed field.
I want to prove the following:

1. Every $2$-dimensional $k$-algebra with only one prime ideal is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^2)$.
2. Not every $3$-dimensional $k$-algebra with only one prime ideal is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^3)$.

For the $2$-dimensional case my attempt goes as follows:

If $A$ is a $2$-dimensional $k$-algebra with exactly one prime ideal then there is a polynomial ring $S$ such that $A=S/I$ for some ideal $I$. Also $A$ is spanned by equivalence classes of monomials, so we can refine it to a basis of two elements $m_1, m_2$. Because $1\in A$ we need one of the monomials to be a unit, and in that case we can replace it by $1$. So, we have that $A$ has a basis of the form $\{1,m\}$ where $m$ is the equivalence class of a monomial. Here I find a fork on the road. There are some possibilities about how to proceed

1. I can argue that the ideal generated by $m$ is maximal, so $m$ is in fact the class of a variable, and then $S$ **must be a polynomial ring in exactly that variable.** I'm not sure of how to prove this but I have a hunch it's true. Then, $S$ being a polynomial in one variable I should prove that $x^2\in I$; I'm not sure how to do it. I know that there would be some $n$ such that $x^n\in I$. I think I could use some argument on the dimension that if $x^2$ is not in $I$ then it cannot be expressed in the form $a+bx+I$, a contradiction.
2. In the case **that's** not true, then I should find a way to make sure that still $x^2\in I$ and that the obvious map $k[x]/(x^2)\to A$ mapping $x$ to itself is an isomorphism. I'm not sure if I can guarantee that. This would be wishful thinking, I think.

For the $3$-dimensional case, I'm not sure how to start. I think that if $A$ is a quotient of a polynomial ring in $1$ variable an argument like the one in 1 should make it isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^3)$, so I think I need a multivariate counterexample. But I'm not sure where to start.

Edit: As diracdeltafunk comments, it's not necesarily true that $S$ must be a polynomial in exactly one variable, but can something similar be said still? Something like that if $S$ has more than one variable, then $I$ is an ideal in which the remaining variables are generators? I mean, there could still be a counterexample.

Comment: Is there a convenient quotient of $k[x,y]$?

Comment: A comment: it's not necessarily true that $S$ must be a polynomial ring in one variable. For example, $k[x,y]/((x-3)^2,y)$ is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easier way to approach this. Suppose $A$ is a 2-dimensional $k$-algebra with exactly one prime ideal. There are two possibilities:

1. $0$ is prime (hence $A$ is a domain)
2. The unique maximal ideal $m$ of $A$ is not equal to $0$ (hence $\dim_k m = 1$)

In case 1, we have that $A$ is a domain. Therefore, for all $a \in A \setminus \{0\}$, $x \mapsto ax : A \to A$ is an injective $k$-linear map. Since $\dim_k A$ is finite, this implies that $x \mapsto ax$ is bijective, so $a$ is a unit in $A$. Thus, $A$ is a field, so $A$ is an extension of $k$ of degree $2$. This is impossible because $k$ is algebraically closed!

Since case 1 was impossible, we better find some way to prove that $A$ is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^2)$ in case 2. In other words, we want to build an isomorphism $k[x]/(x^2) \to A$, so in particular we need to define a morphism $k[x]/(x^2) \to A$. The "only" way to do this is to use the universal properties of $k[x]$ and quotient rings: given an element $a \in A$ such that $a^2 = 0$, $[p] \mapsto p(a) : k[x]/(x^2) \to A$ is a well-defined $k$-algebra homomorphism, and every $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[x]/(x^2) \to A$ can be produced uniquely in this way.

If this is going to be possible, and we do end up proving that $A \cong k[x]/(x^2)$ in case 2, it must be the case that the maximal ideal of $A$ corresponds to $(x)$ via this isomorphism. Thus, the easy way to produce an element of $A$ which squares to $0$ should be to pick an element of the maximal ideal $m$! Is there a best element to choose? Well, $0$ is definitely the worst element to choose, since then the induced map $k[x]/(x^2) \to A$ is $p \mapsto p(0)$, which can't be an isomorphism because its image is $1$-dimensional! However, since in case 2 we have that $\dim_k m = 1$, we see that there is a *unique* choice of nonzero element of $m$, up to scaling (the scaling doesn't matter because $p \mapsto p(a)$ and $p \mapsto p(xa)$ have the same range for any $x \in k \setminus \{0\}$ and $a \in A$ – you should absolutely check this if it's not 100% clear why).

So, let's make that choice: let $a \in m \setminus \{0\}$ be arbitrary and define $f : k[x]/(x^2) \to A$ by $f(p) = p(a)$ (check that this is a well-defined $k$-algebra homomorphism if you're unfamiliar with the aforementioned universal properties). Now we want to show that $f$ is either injective or surjective ($k$-linearity will take care of the rest). Either is easy, but surjectivity is easiest. Since $0 \neq 1 \notin m$, $0 \neq a \in m$, and $\dim_k A = 2$, we must have that $A = \operatorname{span}_k\{1,a\}$. At the same time, we have $1, a \in \operatorname{img}(f)$, since $f(1) = 1$ and and $f(x) = a$. $f$ is $k$-linear, so we conclude that $f$ is surjective, and we are done.

Comment: Just a remark over the first case: Since $A$ has exactly one prime ideal, $0$ being prime means $0$ is also maximal and $A$ is a field so the argument can be shortened. However after reading the remainder of the answer, I think  you were trying to explain it down to every detail, using the least amount of theory possible, which is also nice. You even explained the classic linear algebra theorem about linear monomorphism/epimorphisms being isomorphisms.

I'll check if trying to reproduce the proof in $\dim_k=3$ gives me an idea of why there is a counterexample there.

Comment: Haha that's a good point, I did somehow miss that shortcut in case 1. It is good to know the general fact that a finite-dimensional domain over a field is always a field, though (regardless of how many ideals it might have *a priori*)

Comment: Another side note: the algebraically-closed assumption is needlessly strong; the exact same proof shows that for any field $k$ and any $2$-dimensional $k$-algebra $A$, either $A$ is a field or $A \cong k[x]/(x^2)$. Note in particular that there are fields which are quadratically closed but not algebraically closed (e.g. the constructible numbers).

Comment: An idea for the dimension 3 case seems straightforward. The case 2 in the proof above is replaced by "The unique maximal ideal m of A is not equal to 0, hence $\dim_k m=1$ or $\dim_k m=2$." We only need to find one case when the dimension is $1$ and one when the dimension is $2$.

Comment: I just figured out an example and my previous comment is not what worked out. I'll post it as a complementary answer and leave yours as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This is about the case when $\dim_k A=3$.

Consider the $k$-algebras $A_1=k[x]/(x^3)$ and $A_2=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$.
As vector spaces, $A_1$ is generated by $1,x,x^2$ and $A_2$ is generated by $1,x,y$ so they're both $3-$dimensional. The prime ideals of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are $(x)/(x^3)$ and $(x,y)/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ respectively (since $\text{rad}(x^2,xy,y^2)=(x,y)$, a maximal ideal).

I claim these two algebras are nonisomorphic. To prove it I'll just prove their ideal lattices are nonisomorphic.

First, the ideals of $A_1$ are in a $1-1$ lattice-preserving correspondence (which also preserves prime ideals) with the ideals $(f)$ of $k[x]$ containing $(x^3)$. The generator $f$ of any such ideal must divide $x^3$, so, up to a scalar the choices are $f\in \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. This means that the ideal lattice of $A_1$ is just a chain
$$\begin{matrix} A_1\\
\uparrow\\
(x)/(x^3)\\
\uparrow\\
(x^2)/(x^3)\\
\uparrow\\
0
\end{matrix}$$

Similarly, the ideals of $A_2$ are in a $1-1$ lattice-preserving correspondence (which also preserves prime ideals) with the ideals of $k[x,y]$ containing $I=(x^2,xy,y^2)$. The primary decomposition of $I$ is
$$I=(y^2,x)\cap (x^2,y).$$
Since $y\notin (y^2,x)$ and $x\notin (x^2,y)$ those ideals form an antichain, which wouldn't be possible if the ideal lattice of $A_2$ were a chain. This is, the ideal lattice of $A_2$ contains the following sublattice:
$$\begin{matrix}  & &(x,y)/I& & \\
&\nearrow & & \nwarrow&\\
(x^2,y)/I & & & & (x,y^2)/I\\
& \nwarrow & & \nearrow&\\
 & &0 & &  \end{matrix}$$

Comment: Very nice. Alternatively, for any ring homomorphism $\varphi : k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2) \to k[x]/(x^3)$, we have $\varphi(x) = a+bx+cx^2$ and $\varphi(y) = d+ex+fx^2$ for some $a,b,c,d,e,f \in k$. Now by direct computation, $\varphi(x)^2 = \varphi(y)^2 = 0$ forces $a=b=d=e=0$. This means that the image of $\varphi$ is contained in the subring $\{\alpha+\beta x^2 : \alpha,\beta \in k\}$ of $k[x]/(x^3)$, so $\varphi$ is not surjective.